# Use numeric variable input as days to make date_add work in SparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I have days and reference date that I want to use to get the correct date using SparkR. Here is a toy data and code:

```
library(magrittr)
library(SparkR)


df <- tibble::tribble(
        ~days,  ~date,
        17000L, "1970-01-01",
        17200L, "1970-01-01")
df_spark <- SparkR::as.DataFrame(df)
```

This works:

```
df_spark <- df_spark %>% 
  SparkR::mutate(date2 = date_add(to_date(df_spark$date), 17000))
```

But, this doesn't.

```
df_spark <- df_spark %>% 
  SparkR::mutate(date2 = date_add(to_date(df_spark$date), df_spark$days))
```

It throws an error:

```
unable to find an inherited method for function ‘date_add’ for signature ‘"Column", "Column"’
```

I want to be able to provide column "days" as 2nd argument to date_add instead of number as there are many different values to "days". How should I do that? If it's not possible with date_add, what's the other solution in SparkR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `date_add` directly you should use `expr`:

```
expressiondf_spark <- df_spark %>% 
  SparkR::mutate(date2 = expr("date_add(to_date(date), days)"))

expressiondf_spark %>% head()
```

```
   days       date      date2                                                   
1 17000 1970-01-01 2016-07-18
2 17200 1970-01-01 2017-02-03
```